# Why does the monetary fine portion of a law seem so much less severe than the prison time?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, legal-history

I have over time seen many US laws where the text reads a penalty of $1000 or 1 year imprisonment. The latest one I’ve seen was on my Twitter feed:

[image]

But I’ve seen many like this over the years. Is this due to inflation from when the law was written? Is there no mechanism in place to automatically adjust the financial penalty? Does this problem/phenomenon have a name?